# How do you specify the foreign key column value in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, exception, orm, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

One of my models has the following relationship:

```
class User(Base):
    account     = relationship("Account")
```

I would like to set the account id manually.

My first attempt was this:

```
class User(Base):
    account     = relationship("Account")
    accounts_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("accounts.id"), nullable=True)

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json):
        appointment = Appointment()
        appointment.account_id = json["account_id"]
        return appointment
```

The above dosen't work. We can't refer to this column because SQLAlchemy throws a fit. This is the exception:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Implicitly combining column users.accounts_id with column users.accounts_id under attribute 'accounts_id'.  Please configure one or more attributes for these same-named columns explicitly.
```

I've tried hunting through the docs and expermiented with getting to the attribute numerous ways but I haven't been able to find, much less set it.

```
  print(self.account.account_id)
  print(self.account.relationhip)
  print(self.account.properties)
  print(self.account.primaryjoin)
```

Any ideas?

[Edit- added exception above]

Comment: your classmethod is a bit incoherent.  where is `self` supposed to come from?  Have you elided a `self = cls()`?

Comment: @SingleNegationElimination - fixed it to reflect what i actually have

Comment: What happens with that declaration, and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: How are you calling `User.from_json()`?  Do you have any data you're trying to work with?

Comment: @SingleNegationElimination - Yes, I pass it a JSON dicitionary. I added an exception above to more accurately reflect the issue. My custom constructors work well but the property can't be set because of an `InvalidRequestError` from the ORM

Comment: @Makoto - added the exception I'm getting. I would like to be able to set the account_id without passing an account to the constructor. I figure that if it has the account_id, it should get the correct account if I were to ask for it via lazy load and at least let me do an insert withouht having to go back down to the DB to fetch the account.

Comment: @SingleNegationElimination - the dictionary passed into from_json must have this: `{'account_id':12}` or it will throw an exception

Comment: @ovatsug25 What's your `Base` look like? What is the second line of `from_json` supposed to do? There's not enough info here to solve your issue. You should have no issue setting `account_id` instead of `account` if everything is configured properly.

Comment: Could you please show the definition of the Account class? Also there is a typo: accounts_id vs. account_id

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `Account` class to define the `relationship`, and add the `backref` keyword argument:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class User(Base):

    accounts_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('account.id'))

class Account(Base):

    users = relationship('User', backref='account')
```

> When the `backref` keyword is used on a single relationship, it’s exactly the same as if the above two relationships were created individually using `back_populates` on each.

**References**

- [Linking Relationships with Backref](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/backref.html)
- [Controlling Cascade on Backrefs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html#backref-cascade)
- [SQLAlchemy ORM Examples](http://pythoncentral.io/sqlalchemy-orm-examples/)